# how should I deploy of react-redux api website?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, hosting

I have React website code (with redux code also to integrate API in website) when I host it on Github-pages or Netlify or firebase, it shows front end only, API is not integrated on hosting  (API works fine on localhost)

how to integrate redux API on hosting (for free or paid)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the code? As long as the API is served using a suitable backend server that is hosted appropriately, changing the BASE_URL should do the trick. I am assuming the code that you have deployed still used `localhost:5000` or any localhost base url. Like you had in dev environment.

Comment: I cannot share it, because it is confidential for the company, but I assure you that it has no errors, I think you want to say that I should change the base URL of API,          also kindly suggest me free hosting website, please.       an thanks for responding to my issue

Comment: I am not sure about how big of a backend you have but you can look into gh-pages, netlify, firebase, etc to host your react application atleast. The size of the backend would then determine if you can host the backend for free somewhere or will you have to pay for servers.

Comment: I have a very small backend with just 1 API used in it as a startup.

Comment: Then you can easily host your backend on netlify or maybe the free tier of AWS lambda.

Comment: yeah but I have used API to list down all countries(using redux also) , I can see API data on localhost but on on netlify deployed app

Comment: I cannot help a lot unless I get to see the code. I understand it is confidential so you can atleast provide minimal reproducible code